# Modify UI from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, connection, broadcastreceiver

I need some way to detect when the network connection has been lost.
So a switch between mobile and wifi doesn't really matter it's just to detect at runtime when the connection has been lost.

I now have found some code which works fine for me.

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Log.d(ConnectivityReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "action: "
              + intent.getAction());
  }

}
```

I want to check inside the onReceive() method wheter or not a connection is still available or not.

The thing is, that I want to show a message to the user, if it has been lost. So what's the best way of passing back to my Activity, that the connection has been lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to track network connection state only when activity is on screen you can place your `ConnectivityReceiver` as inner nested class in `Activity`. In this case you should register it in `onResume` method and unregister it in `onPause`. It will look like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(ConnectivityReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "action: "
                + intent.getAction());
        }
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new ConnectivityReceiver();

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you! How do I register and unregister this Receiver?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Methods [registerReceiver]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter) and [unregisterReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver)) should be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an inner Class which extends `BroadcastReceiver` and you can dynamically [register](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29) it. From the innterclass(precisely `onRecieve()` method) you can access your Activity.